# How do i enable --with-http_cookie_module in my docker nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I want to use pass cookies from the client to the server and have nginx read these cookies and set certain proxy_pass parameters based on this

I am using this in my nginx docker file

```
FROM nginx:latest
```

and these are the modules enables when running `nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.25.2
built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
built with OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_v3_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.25.2/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.25.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

Is there a way to get a docker image with this flag already activated? I saw there is an option for ENABLED_MODULES in my docker-compose but unsure what image i can use. Is there a reason why its not included by default?

Comment: perhaps this is not needed anymore- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/cookie-flag/